# Material UI v5 Migration - Slider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to migrate some legacy React code from Material UI v4 to v5 and I don't quite understand how to fix my Slider component. I've read [this guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/) and, from what I can get, it seems I've to replace *withStyles*, but I can't understand how to achieve it.

Thank you!

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

const PrettoSlider = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "#4791db",
    height: 8,
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "2px solid currentColor",
    marginTop: -8,
    marginLeft: -12,
    "&:focus, &:hover, &$active": {
      boxShadow: "inherit",
    },
  },
  active: {},
  valueLabel: {
    left: "calc(-50% + 4px)",
  },
  track: {
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  rail: {
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
})(Slider);

export default PrettoSlider;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding:

```
import { withStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```